# I want whenever I create a sprint in Jira a new branch should be created from develop branch

Tags: github-actions, jira, jira-plugin

I tried many things but didn't able to figure it out

I was searching in the Jira Actions but then I searched on google and found out that they don't provide something like this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something that did not work ? or you are just looking for some a guideline ?

As i see it you will need to execute a webhook from Jira to git every time a sprint has been created in jira, the webhook should call a ci pipeline that execute some git basic commands like

```bash
# checkout the develop branch
git checkout develop
# create a new branch based on the develop branch
git checkout -b <new-branch>
# push the new branch to the remote.
git push -u <remote> <new-branch>
```